# Restore rman backup on another server with a higher Oracle release

Tags: backup, restore, rman, oracle-9i

I would like to know if it is possible to restore a full backup made with rman of an Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release **9.2.0.6.0** on another server with Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release **9.2.0.8.0**, I have the doubt precisely in the change of versions of 9.2.0.**6**.0 to 9.2.0.**8**.0.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The data dictionary versions/contents won't match. You would need to restore to the same version and then do an upgrade of the restored database. Either that or create an empty database in 9.2.0.8 and use exp/imp to migrate just your data and other application-specific content, rather than RMAN.